# inserting data into excel using java

Tags: java, sql, excel, syntax, odbc

I am buliding a stand alone application using java swing. and excel 2007 sheet as the backend for storing my data. There are 15 columns in the excel sheet. I am able to insert data into it with just 5 columns. But it shows "syntax error" when i try inserting 15 columns. Is there any limit on the the number of columns that can inserted at a time? or is there any other syntax for lengthy records? I am new to java. so kindly help me out. Thanks in advance :) i have posted the part of the coding

```
 try
                       {

                         String value1=t1.getText();

                         String value2=(String)c6.getSelectedItem();

                         String value3=t3.getText();

                         String value4=t4.getText();

                         String value5=t5.getText();

                         String value6 = (String) c4.getSelectedItem(); 

                         String value7=t7.getText();

                         String value8=t8.getText();

                         String value9 = (String) c1.getSelectedItem(); 

                         String value10 = (String) c2.getSelectedItem(); 

                         String value11 = (String) c5.getSelectedItem(); 

                         String value12 = (String) c3.getSelectedItem(); 

                         String value13=t13.getText();

                         String value14=t14.getText();

                         String value15=t15.getText();

           //connection to the database          

                  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
               Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:testingApp");

          //Execute some sql and load the records into the resultset
                  Statement st=con.createStatement();
                String q = "insert into [sheet1$] (CRN,CR_NUM,SOW_N,PSM,LBG,TYPE,VALUE,REMARKS,STATUS,APPROVAL,PLATFORM,MODEL,START_DATE,END_DATE,CUM_VALUE) values ('"+value1+"','"+value2+"','"+value3+"','"+value4+"','"+value5+"','"+value6+"','"+value7+"','"+value8+"','"+value9+"','"+value10+"','"+value11+"','"+value12+"','"+value13+"','"+value14+"','"+value15+"')";
                 int ds = st.executeUpdate(q);
                 System.out.println("Inserted Sucessfully...!!!");

                  /* t1.setText(null);
                    c6.addItem(null);
                    t3.setText(null);
                    t4.setText(null);
                    t5.setText(null);
                    c4.addItem(null);
                    t7.setText(null);
                    t8.setText(null);
                    c1.addItem(null);
                    c2.addItem(null);
                    c5.addItem(null);
                    c3.addItem(null); 
                    t13.setText(null);
                    t14.setText(null);
                    t15.setText(null); */
                    }catch(Exception e)
                       {
                           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

}
```

Comment: Would any of your data contain the ' character?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have xls/xlsx format then as sp00m sai, Apache POI is best solution,
if you want to have csv file, then just create text file and write there data separating columns with comma and rows with "\n" character

Comment: no they dont contain character..only string and numeric values

Comment: where can i find tutorials for Apache POI ? what is the difference? why doesnt it work here? this same logic worked for two columns. sorry iam asking too many questions at a time. but iam desperate here. been working on this for past 3 days. no solution yet. please help me.

Comment: i unchecked read-only in the ODBC connection and also added it in code like READONLY=false but it still doesnt work. Can anyone tell me where iam going wrong?

Comment: 1) can you get data from db?
2) for poi, i recommend you to start from http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html
3) difference what i meantion is in excel file format, xlsx is format for excel 2007+, xls is older excel format, both are supported by poi, but you need to use different classes, csv is just regular text file, but it can be opened and edited in excel as regular excel file

Comment: oh ok ok. i went through the coding again. checked the SQL state which returned as 1. also i tried printing one of the values in the cmd screen. it worked. But when i open the excel file it said 'read only. locked for editing' so i tried to close the connection after insertion. ( con.close() ) after that it worked :) so because the connection was open, the program couldnt edit it since it was open. so after closing it worked. Thanks a lot everyone. Anyway iam going to try apache poi also. its seems easier. Thanks ya :)